# PHP - Trouble adding multiple drop down menu options to MySQL

Tags: php, implode, mysql-real-escape-string

I'm having difficulty adding multiple drop down menu options to a MySQL database. I obtained the following code from [freezecoders.com](http://freezecoders.com/2012/08/how-to-insert-multiple-values-using-dropdown-list-box-in-php.html)

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" action="index.php">
Select your favourite game:<br/>
<select name="game[]" multiple="multiple">
<option>Football</option>
<option>Volleyball</option>
<option>Badminton</option>
<option>Cricket</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$query=mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db("freeze",$query);
$choice=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['game']);
$choice1=implode(',',$choice);
mysql_query("insert into tb values('','$choice1')");
}

?>
```

When I run this code I keep getting error messages relating to `mysql_real_escape_string()` and  `implode()` functions.

```
The error message are "Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in C:\WAMP\www\COSHH\test\index.php on line 8"
```

And

```
"Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed in C:\WAMP\www\COSHH\test\index.php on line 9"
```

Unfortunately for me I'm not experienced in using these functions. Can someone please point out what's going wrong for me here? I'm using `WAMP (PHP 5.3.8)` and `Google Chrome (Version 24.0.1312.52)`

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string` works with strings, not with arrays of strings.

Comment: Thanks Bart, do you have a suggestion as to what I should use instead?

Comment: That's because `name="game[]"` creates an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Bart said mysql_real_escape_string works with strings, not with arrays.
The reason your `$_POST['game']` is an array is because you have it named `game[]`. You can try with one value if you change the name to `game`.

Although we want the code to work with multiple choices. You can change the PHP code like this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $query=mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
    mysql_select_db("freeze",$query);
    $choice = array();
    foreach($_POST['game'] as $game) {
        $choice[]=mysql_real_escape_string($game);
    }
    $choice1=implode(',',$choice);
    mysql_query("insert into tb values('','$choice1')");
}
?>
```

By the way, can you tell us what is your database structure? It seems you are making a big mistake with saving all the values the user picked in just one cell. It should work, but it's not a very good way of storing data in database (it's not compilant with any data bases standards).

**EDIT:**

Also I noticed there is an easier way to fix it (it seems someone who wrote the code misplaced two lines):

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $query=mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
    mysql_select_db("freeze",$query);
    $choice=implode(',',$_POST['game']);
    $choice1=mysql_real_escape_string($choice);
    mysql_query("insert into tb values('','$choice1')");
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Kelu, much appreciated. It inserts the data into my database now.

Comment: My database structure; CREATE TABLE  `freeze`.`tb` (
  `id` int(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=47 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;